# Azure Function | PowerShell | Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng'

Tags: azure, powershell, powerbi, azure-functions, powershell-7.0

I have an azure function app with runtime version ~3 and powershell version 7.0 creating a connection to powerbi that is connecting to azure active directory.

```
Import-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

$id=$user
$password=$token | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $id, $password

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential
```

Throws an exception `Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly`

Above script works fine on powershell version 5.1 however not able to use old version on Azure Functions.

Tried to import with UseWindowsPowerShell `Import-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -UseWindowsPowerShell` however it also throws an exception `ERROR: Failed to generate proxies for remote module 'MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt'. Running the Get-Command command in a remote session returned no results.`

Not able to understand why creating a connection to active directory is so hard and cumbersome, could anyone please help to resolve the above issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The fix is available at:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt/1.2.0.

Please update your function app to use this module.

---

[That class isn't supported by .NET Core and .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256cng?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=netframework-4.8), Powershell 7 is built on top of .NET Core and thus can't load the assembly. You'll need to stick to Windows Powershell 5.1 (which uses the .NET 4 runtime) or the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt needs to be updated to not create the specific Sha256 implementation, see [dotnet/runtime#25044 (comment)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25044#issuecomment-520203003).

[image]

There's a GitHub issue tracking the issue:

- https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/issues/288

As a workaround, [it looks like you should be able to auth using a certificate of a service principal](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/issues/288#issuecomment-820078102):

> MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt works well on desktop PowerShell 7.1.0 using service principal and auth by cert.

Comment: Oh, good to know it is a known issue. Since I am using email id & password, I does not have service principal and its thumbprint.

Comment: Looks like another workaround people are using is to invoke a PS5 session from PS7. A bit ugly,but I'm guessing they need to update a few dependencies.

Comment: This is an issue that I have run into as well.  Here's another thread with Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/339901/34could-not-load-type-39systemsecuritycryptography.html?childToView=370002#comment-370002).  Incidentally, I have submitted a ticket with my Azure team to investigate the issue as it is impacting implementation into production for me as well.  I'll post here if I find a solution.